# Inicialização Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

É possível desabilitar a checagem que o Hibernate faz toda vez que o app é iniciado?

Ou seja, no momento em que crio as classes da tabela e seto as colunas, é normal que na primeira vez em que o app for executado o hibernate crie as tabelas de acordo com entidades setadas.

Entretanto, a partir disso, toda vez que o app é executo ele continua fazendo checagem nas tabelas, sendo que nenhuma foi alterada, fazendo com que assim eu perca velocidade na iniciação do app.

> Abaixo um exemplo da checagem...

```
set 29, 2014 5:34:33 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
set 29, 2014 5:34:34 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
set 29, 2014 5:34:34 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
set 29, 2014 5:34:34 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: casa
    ...]
set 29, 2014 5:34:34 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
set 29, 2014 5:34:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
set 29, 2014 5:34:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
set 29, 2014 5:34:35 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
set 29, 2014 5:34:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
set 29, 2014 5:34:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.199/casadochopp]
set 29, 2014 5:34:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
set 29, 2014 5:34:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
set 29, 2014 5:34:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
set 29, 2014 5:34:37 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
set 29, 2014 5:34:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.people
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [address, mail, city, phone, cpf, name, id, cnpj, sexo, type]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.settings
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [idsettings, cardstart, cardend]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.comandas
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [people_id, codcom, datecom, desconto, hourcom, card, status]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_bnw9l1qcofp9oyvm9ge9rktkp]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_bnw9l1qcofp9oyvm9ge9rktkp, primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.itens_comandas
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [namepro, coditen, qtdpro, comanda_codcom, valorpro, product_codpro]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_rmbxevv5ruo62sa34wgdmga41, fk_6038pgoa0827b30p9abx9qqbo]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_rmbxevv5ruo62sa34wgdmga41, fk_6038pgoa0827b30p9abx9qqbo, primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.itens_nota
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [coditensnote, qtd, note_codnote, cost, product_codpro]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_ac1tn94l5w66ul77d1nbme6b8, fk_98jgeuv3wtt1vobumpjva7ujq]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_ac1tn94l5w66ul77d1nbme6b8, fk_98jgeuv3wtt1vobumpjva7ujq, primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.notes
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [numnote, people_id, datanote, dataent, shippnote, totalnote, codnote, despesasnote]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_h7em46letmwtmko1di56kbqpl]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_h7em46letmwtmko1di56kbqpl, primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.products
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [namepro, vigorprice, price2pro, category_codpcat, descriptionpro, costpro, codpro, price1pro, stockpro]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_s8p92nu65sd00m7kooorw3dl3]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_s8p92nu65sd00m7kooorw3dl3, primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.products_category
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [productcategory, codpcat, categorydescription]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.users
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [nameuser, passuser, tipuser, coduser, namecat, categoria_coducat]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_cpj6mheomcmqjq5lcpi4l6xyw]
set 29, 2014 5:34:41 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_cpj6mheomcmqjq5lcpi4l6xyw, primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: casadochopp.users_category
set 29, 2014 5:34:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [coducat, levelucat, nameucat]
set 29, 2014 5:34:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
set 29, 2014 5:34:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
set 29, 2014 5:34:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente você tem a propriedade de configuração `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` em algum arquivo de configuração.

Apenas remova ou comente a configuração acima para que o Hibernate não faça mais a verificação.

Aparentemente, segundo [uma resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179948/1683070), é possível também usar o valor `none` para esta propriedade, porém não é recomendado visto que [não consta na documentação](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html).

Comment: Muito obrigado.